# Automating import of data-tier application (SQL database) from Azure with a Master Key

Tags: database, powershell, azure, extract

When I extract a data-tier application from a Microsoft Azure SQL database that has a Master Key, I was unable to import it into SQL server on my local PC.

You will find others had this issue here: [SSMS 2016 Error Importing Azure SQL v12 bacpac: master keys without password not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575610/ssms-2016-error-importing-azure-sql-v12-bacpac-master-keys-without-password-not)

However the steps provided as the answer did not work on my installation.
Steps are
1. Disable auditing on the server (or database)
2. Drop the database master key with DROP MASTER KEY command.

**Microsoft Tech Support verified this solution did not work on my installation of SQL Server** and after actually taking remote control of my PC and trouble shooting, **they were unable to determine why this was occurring**.

I needed to find a way to remove the Master Key from the bacpac file.  I have a Powershell script to remove the Master Key from the BACPAC file but it requires extracting, renaming files and running scripts from Windows Powershell to get the db imported.

Does anyone have a program or set of scripts which would automate the process of removing the Master Key and importing a SQL DB from Azure with a single command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am new to this forum.  Please do not be harsh with this post.  I am trying to do the best I can to help others to save the many hours I spent coming up with this.

I have cobbled together a T-SQL script which calls a Windows Powershell script (also cobbled from multiple sources) to extract a data-tier application (database) from Microsoft Azure SQL database and import it into a database on my local SQL Server by running ONE command.  Over the months I found some of the code that is in my scripts from other blogs etc.  I am not able to provide the credit due to those folks as I didn't keep track of where I got the info.  If you are reading this and you see your code, please take credit.  I apologize for not being able to give you the credit for your work.

There may be configuration settings on your PC and your local SQL server that need adjustments as this entire solution requires pretty much full access to your computer.  If you run into trouble with compatibility, let me know and I will do the best I can to let you know how my system is configured in case it will help you.

I am using Windows 10 Pro and Microsoft SQL Server Developer (64-bit) v12.0.5207.0

I have placed the two files that do all the work on GitHub here: https://github.com/Wingloader/Auto-Azure-BACPAC-Download.git
GetNewBacpac-forGitHub.sql
GetAzureDB-forGitHub.ps1

---

WARNING: The Powershell script file will store your SQL sa password and your Azure SQL login in clear text!
If you don't want to do this, don't use this solution.

---

My computer is owned and controlled solely by me so I am able to open up the security in my system and I am willing to assume the responsibility of safeguarding it.

The basic steps of my solution are are accomplished as follows: (steps 1 and 2 are optional as I like to keep a version of the DB I am working with as of the point in time I pull down a clean production copy of my Azure DB)

1. Back up the current DB as MyLocalDB.bak.
2. Restore that backup from step 1 to a new DB with the previous day stamped at the end of the DB name (e.g., MyLocalDB20171231)
3. Delete the original MyLocalDB database (needed so we can recreate the DB with the original name later on)
4. Pull down the production database from Azure and create a new database with the name MyLocalDB.

The original DB is deleted in step 3 so that the restored DB can use the original name (important when you have data connections referring to that DB name)

In Step 4, the work of extracting the data-tier application DB from Azure is initiated by this line in the T-SQL:

```
EXEC MASTER..xp_cmdshell '%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File C:\Git\GetUpdatedAzureDB\GetAzureDB.ps1"'
```

The Powershell script does the following:

1. The target for the extract is a file named today.bacpac (hardcoded).  The first thing to do is delete that file if it already exists.
2. Extract the DB from Azure into the today.bacpac file.

Note: my DB on Azure has a Master Key for encryption.  This will need to be removed from the files prior to importing the bacpac file into your local DB or it will fail (this may not be required in SQL 2017 according to my previous conversations with MS Support).  If you do not use a Master Key, you can either strip out the code that does this step or just leave it alone.  It won't remove anything if it isn't there.  It would just add a little overhead to the program.

3. Open the today.bacpac file (zip file) and remove the MasterKey node from the Origin.xml file.
4. Modify the Model.xml file to updates the SHA hash length.  This is required in order for the file not to appear to have been tampered with when SQL opens the bacpac file.
5. Re-zips the files back into a new file today-patched.bacpac
6. Runs this line of code (from Powershell) to import the bacpac file into SQL Server

   ```
   &C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" /Action:Import /SourceFile:"C:\Git\GetUpdatedAzureDB\today-patched.bacpac" /TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=MyLocalSQLServer;User ID=sa; Password=MySAPassword; Initial Catalog=MyLocalDB; Integrated Security=false;"
   ```

After editing the two files to provide updated paths, usernames and passwords, run the SQL script.  You do not need to edit the scripts again.  You can run the SQL script again without modification and it will create a new copy of your Azure DB.

Done!